# Ransack search: one input field for two fields with relevance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have this piece of code

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: "/venues/search", method: "post", id: "frm_search_venue", class: "col-md-6" do |f| %>
                <%= f.text_field :name_or_description_cont, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

in a RoR app with Ransack. It works perfect, it searches in the "name" and "description" field from my model (Venue).

The thing is: can I define with Ransack some kind of relevance in the search? In other words, the result search array come with the models that the "name" attribute matches the parameter, later the description?

Or is it better to use other search pattern/approach, such as with Elastic search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track - I would use Elastic search (or something similar) to add relevancy to this search query.

The approach could involve giving a weight to the name and description (name would be 0.9 or 1.0 whereas description would be 0.6 or 0.5)

You might also want to take a look at Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

There's a version of Solr for Rails applications call Sunspot. It should provide the functionality that you're looking for.

http://www.github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Comment: this is something I was "afraid". I chose Ransack 'cause it doesn't rely on other application and the app I'm working didn't need a powerful search engine. But it has grown and I know that some things it will need for the search engine will require relevance (and maybe phonetic search). Do you know if there's some kind of free "SOLR" could service? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @OhHendrie I switched to Sunspot and everything is working ok now :-)

Comment: Good stuff. I'll edit the answer to include sunspot :)